# How do I resolve this Import Error in the MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use the mysql.connector to connect to MySQL.
Here are the steps that I took -

1. pip install --user mysql-connector-python

```
$ pip install --user mysql-connector-python
Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/f3/28cb22dc644c6de783ff0111a4ee02233c43963421dbdc2390b587d48078/mysql_connector_python-8.0.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.0.0 (from mysql-connector-python)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/9f3cb458266ef5cdeaa1e72a90b9eda100e3d1803cbd7ec02f0846da83c3/protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: protobuf, mysql-connector-python
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.26 protobuf-3.18.0
```

2. On a terminal I typed python, to test the import.

```
>>> import mysql.connector

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user1/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import version
ImportError: cannot import name version
```

I am on Python 2.7.16

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

I am trying to understand what I could do here to get the import to work. Please help if you have seed this in the past and can advise on how I could get past this error.

Comment: What happens if you do `python2.7  -m pip install mysql-connector-python`?

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (8.0.26)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.18.0)
`

Comment: I don't know exactly why the import fails, but the package's [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) declares that the module is only available for Python 3.  As Python 2 has  reached its end of life, are you able to upgrade to Python 3?